# Video conversion too long

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg

I use NReco.VideoConverter for convert flv to ogv. But this process is too long. I tried to convert 200M video but it took more than hour. The code I use:

```
var ffMpeg = new FFMpegConverter();
command = String.Format("-i \"{0}\" -c:v libtheora -c:a libvorbis -preset ultrafast \"{1}\"", inputFile, outputFile);
ffMpeg.Invoke(command);
```

Could anyone suggest me how to improve the performance of conversion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theora does not have an `ultrafast` preset, or presets at all. Please show the complete, uncut command line output from the raw command rather than the C# stuff around it. Do you really need Theora/Vorbis encoding? What's your application?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a site where users can upload videos which I show on pages. I want to show videos in all browsers and platforms. Therefore I convert each video in two formats - mp4 and ogv. As I understand mp4 covers almost all browser and platforms except Opera and Firefox. For these two browsers I use ogv.

Comment: Btw, conversion to mp4 is pretty fast.

Comment: If you want browser compatibility, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility -- you could use VP8 which should be faster to encode (depending on the settings).

Comment: @IlyaShpakovsky - did you found any solution to convert video from mp4 to other formats?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf "crop=640:256:0:400" -threads 5 -preset ultrafast -strict -2 YourCroppedMovie.mp4
```

Comment: Question asker wanted OGV, not MP4.